# Random semi-colon in jQuery source

Tags: jquery

I'm just wondering what purpose the stray semi-colon serves in in this for loop (found in jQuery.js)

```
if ( isArray ) {
 // ... here
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        value = callback( elems[ i ], i, arg );

        if ( value != null ) {
            ret[ ret.length ] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I see it a few times throughout the file.

P.S. Also, how do I get better at reading complex JS? I find it very hard to keep track of things, do you think this is due to a lack of knowledge/experience or should I be reading it a certain way?

Thank you

Comment: It's not stray, the first expression in the for loop is just empty, probably because there's nothing to initialize.

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this. Sure, it's a simple question than an experienced programmer would know. But it does look a little funny, especially to somebody learning to program. The question itself was well worded, provided the source formatted nicely etc. I see no reason to downvote this.

Comment: @mason because it "does not show any research effort." The entry on MDN answers this in one sentence in the summary.

Comment: @DaggNabbit *What* entry on MDN? *What* is MDN? *How* would you Google something like this?

Comment: @mason google "for loop." The excerpt from MDN in the search results reads "Creates a loop that consists of three **optional expressions**, enclosed in parentheses and **separated by semicolons**."

Comment: @DaggNabbit You did not explain *what* MDN is. Do you mean MSDN? The MSDN entry for "for loop" was 9th in my list of results. I had to scroll down to find it. Even then, it doesn't exactly explain what would happen if you left off the first optional expression. So again, this question is just fine, and your justification for downvoting it is unreasonable.

Comment: @mason I mean MDN. See the link in adeneo's answer. Appears above MSDN in search results for "for loop." It doesn't need to explain what happens when you omit the expression, because *nothing* happens. Even the most cursory bit of research about "for loops" would clear up exactly how they work. There is no need for yet another SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` has three optional expressions, they are

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

if no `initialization` is needed, you don't pass anything, but as evident from the above, the semicolon is required to close that expression and move on to the `condition` part

```
for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
```

You can do the same if you don't need the `final-expression`

```
for ( var i=10; i--; )
```

In other words, both semicolons are required, but the expressions are optional and can be empty

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0):

`for` requires three parts, separated by semicolons. In this case the first part, the initialization step, is absent/does nothing.